# Flutter provider not allowing me to access data

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have set up a simple provider in my flutter application, which is as follows:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Data1 {
  int data1 = 0;
  double _data2;
  var _arr = [];
}

class SendDataModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Data1> FinalDataList = new List<Data1>(3);

  void changeOption(int whichone, int whichnumber) {
    FinalDataList[whichone].data1 = whichnumber;  //this is where I am getting the error

    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

I make a call to provider as follows in my code:

```
Provider.of<SendDataModel>(context, listen: false).changeOption(1, int.parse(value));
```

And I am getting the following error:

"The getter 'data1' was called on null."

Can someone please help me with this?  I am trying to have an array of Data1 stored in the state.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're trying to access to .data1 on a null object, when you create your list, not a single Data1 Object was initialized inside.

I would just suggest you to

```
var myData = Data1();
myData.data1 = whichnumber;
FinalDataList[whichone] = myData;
```

of course you have to customize better to your need but the problem again is that your list is full of `null`s

Comment: Hi @Tizianoreica, thanks for helping me out!  I thought the line "List<Data1> FinalDataList = new List<Data1>(3);" initialized it, but obviously I am wrong.  Would you mind providing an example of how to do what I'm trying to do?  I am new to flutter and a little hazy.

Comment: Thanks @Tizianoreica I am looking into it.

Comment: Hi @Tizianoreica.  What if I have some previous data stored and don't want to reinitialize everytime.  Sorry but I'm just really new, would you mind showing me a full example?

Comment: But the provider works correctly itself, the problem was how you initialized your FinalList. In case you want to have a filled list, you can do `List<Data1> FinalDataList = [Data1(values...), Data1(values...), Data1(values...)]` where of course each Data1 has is own values

Comment: Thanks @Tizianoreica!  Can you give me an example of how you would define a "values"?

Comment: Well this is totally not related to the question honestly :) But when you define your class Data1 you can define also variable instances and a constructor. I would suggest you some youtube video maybe to understand what I'm talking about :) You can try to check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7xtib79isdQ